# Regex to identify rows that do not contain exact number of occurences of quotemark character using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to be able to jump to rows that dont contain 6 quotemarks in a quoted-CSV file as it feels like a good way to identify broken rows.

I think using a regular expression with Notepad++'s find features would be a sensible approach but I'm not sure how to pick the rows up.

6 quotemarks (") would suggest a complete row so I want to skip to any row that does not contain 6.

Here is some sample data to play with, in this example its the 4th line I'd like to jump to

```
"sam","mark","dave"
"sam","mark","dave"
"sam","mark","dave"
"sam","mark","
dave"
"sam","mark","dave"
"sam","mark","dave"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find lines where quotes occur between 0 and 5 times, use this regular expression.

```
^([^"\n]*"){0,5}$
```

Explanation:

- `^` - From the beginning of a line
- `([^\n"]*")` - Find a group containing any character except a double quote or a new line (`[^"\n]`), until a double quote (`*"`).
- `{0,5}` - Find lines that contain between 0 and 5 occurrences of the group
- `$` - Until the end of the line

To match also lines that have more than 6 `"` you can use this

```
^(([^"\n]*"){0,5}|([^"\n]*"){7,})$
```

- `|` it puts in OR the two regexes (5 or less OR 7 or more)
- `{7,}` - Find lines that contain 7 or more occurrences of the group

Comment: This found my problem rows for me and the explanation is fantastic - thanks a lot!  Is it possible to to modify it to also find rows with more than 6 quotemarks?

Answer (score 2):

This can help you in finding the correct lines

```
^(.*?"){6}[^"]$
```

you can then bookmark the unmatched lines (the ones you are after) with `search->bookmarks->inverse bookmarks`

**EDIT**:

This pattern instead will match only the lines you want

```
(?!("[^"\r\n]*){6})^.+?$
```

It uses negative lookaheads to tell the search engine to avoid lines with exactly 6 `"` and keep the others.

If it is possible to have more than 6 quotes (and this is also a problem) use the following instead

```
(?!^("[^"\r\n]*){6}$)^.+?$
```

**EDIT**:

- `(?!` this is a negative lookahead, it tells "match strings (or lines) that DO NOT contain the following text"
- `(^"`: The text that should not be matched starts with a `"` *at the beginning of the line* (`^`)
- `[^"\r\n]*`: and after that contains 0 or more (`*`) elements that are not a double quote or newline characters  (if the `^` is the first character inside square brackets the meaning is "dont' find the characters in the brackets")
- `){6}`:repeated 6 times
- `$)`: finishing at the end of the line (and end of the negative lookahead)
- `^.+?$`: AND, if the condition is ok, match the whole line.

Comment: Thanks Gabber, the first example didn't work for me but the second one worked perfectly, is there any chance of you explaining what each part is doing?